# Unexpected Token Function using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that I have set on an interval:

```
function refresh() {
    if ($("#autorefresh").checked) {
        var elem = $("#messagesDiv");
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
    }
}

var autoRefresh = window.setInterval(refresh(), 1000);
```

and a simple checkbox input on the html page. I continue to get an Unexpected Token Function on the `refresh()` function. I already checked for too many commas, too many parentheses, there doesn't seem like anythings wrong in that sense. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var autoRefresh = window.setInterval(refresh(), 1000);
```

needs to be

```
var autoRefresh = window.setInterval(refresh, 1000);
```

and you will find out that

```
$("#autorefresh").checked
```

needs to be

```
$("#autorefresh").prop("checked")
```

and your third problem, there is no scrollTop and scrollHeight properties either, you are NOT working with a DOM element

```
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

should be something like

```
elem.scrollTop(elem[0].scrollHeight);
```

---

The updated code would be

```
function refresh () {
    if ($("#autorefresh").prop("checked")) {
        var elem = $("#messagesDiv");
        elem.scrollTop(elem[0].scrollHeight);
    }
}
var autoRefresh = window.setInterval(refresh, 1000);
```

Running example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7eEcw/

Comment: Indeed, though I can't see why that would give the unexpected token error.

Comment: I pasted this into Visual Studio and its complaining about the `function` syntax, saying that it's missing an ')'

Comment: Is there any other code on the page? The code runs fine the way it is.

Comment: I do have other code in the js file but none of it interacts with the same stuff that these two functions do.

Comment: @GPinskiy "saying that it's missing an ')'". Is there any other information? A line number for example?

Comment: @wared No line number from VS because it was that specific `function` that it marked.

Comment: It does not matter if it interacts, one of those functions could have a `(` that is not closed or missing a `{`. The parser that could also just be wrong. You are going to have to do the rest of the debugging. Start commenting out sections of code and see what is causing it exactly.